# PhotoFrame is displayed when youtube videos playing in WebBrowser

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have written code for playing youtube videos in webbrowser.

**Xaml code:**

```
<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser" Height="411"  IsScriptEnabled="True" Margin="10,100,78,0" />
```

**Xaml.cs code:**

```
 Movie movie;
    public VideoPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var app = App.Current as App;
        movie = app.selectedMovie;

        string video =movie.MovieWatchLink;
        this.webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(video));

    }
```

When I run this code at first white color PhotoFrame is displaying as shown in below figure.
[image]

And when we tap it.Movie starts playing in nativeplayer.And when we want to move back to movies list also this photoframe is displaying.

Please anybody help me how can I remove this.I searched my level best eventhough I didnt get any solution.  Please help me how can I immediately  play after selecting the movie.

ManyThanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try collapsing the visibility of the webBrowser until the video starts streaming in the native player if we can get any handle of media being played in our code.or else you can try showing a thumbnail image related to the video until it starts to stream in player.

Showing thumbnail will be a better choice.

Regards,
Ganesan S

Comment: Thankyou. can you please tell me how can I Collapse the visibility or display a thumnail size video.Thanking you.

Comment: Hi you can position a Image Element and the web browser under a same grid panel , collapse the visibility of the Image Element once the video has been loaded completely and vice-versa.